# How to find out what "kind" of document is being displayed in IE

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, bho

i am using c# to create a button for IE and this button performs certain actions that all depend on the document being a PDF document. I am trying to setup a guard to prevent any action taking place if the document type is not a PDF but not sure how as IE hands over the document to adobe and reader takes charge. I am using both SHDocWv have looked at the WebBrowserClass objects and not sure how to figure this out. any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little bit problematic to do this AFAIK.

Value of *IWebBrowser2::Type* property depends on what plug-in you have installed that handles PDFs, because some plug-ins creates HTML wrapper for PDF file (like Adobe) so you get "HTML Document" as type and some plug-ins don't do this (like Foxit), so you can't relay on this exclusively.

So if you got PDF with HTML wrapper you can use *IHTMLDocument2::mimeType* to find out exact type of the document (JPEG/GIF/PNG/etc. files are all wrapped in HTML by the browser). But as I know it is unreliable too, for instance on my machine it returns "Firefox Document" for HTML documents because .html files are associated with Firefox :s But I didn't test to see if this is the case with PDFs alos.

Another options is to use *GetUrlCacheEntryInfoEx* API call to obtain file in local browser cache which stores document, then read it (only the beginning of the file, I think only the first 256 bytes are important) and call *FindMimeFromData* with data you just read and it will return mime type.

Answer (score 0):

Check mime type of the document or see the window.location.href of webbrowser... If pdf is being displayed, you would be able to find it...

Comment: unable to check URL as some sites return query strings without "pdf" in the address. can you tell me how to access the mime types and from which class / object?

Answer (score 0):

Another good way is to do the following..

1] Cast the Document object to IPersist and then extract the CLSID using .GetClassID(..).
2] pInvoke ProgIDFromCLSID to extract the progId
3] Match the progID against known COM objects / applications.